# why does asynchronous I/O require buffering?

Tags: operating-systems, kernel, io

I read in some introductory lecture notes on I/O and operating systems that "asynchronous systems require buffering". Why is it so please?

Cheers

Comment: why downvote please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a synchronous network (eg. SDH), bitstreams are allocated guaranteed bandwidth. A node in a synchronous network is forwarding individual bits from an ingress interface to an egress interface and thanks to TDM (time division multiplexing), there is always a slot ready for the bit from ingress to be placed onto the egress interface. A buffer (1 bit in size) is needed for each stream, where the bit waits between the ingress and egress allocated TDM slots. 1 bit is so small that it is usually considered 'no buffer'.

In an asynchronous network (eg. ethernet), you never know how many packets are will arrive through an interface and will need to be forwarded to another interface. Bandwidth reservation is not done. An asynchronous node could drop incoming packets if an egress interface is busy, but that would lead to a very large packet loss. Implementing buffers allows packets to be delayed and the bandwidth of the egress interface to be utilized fully. Only when buffers are full, packets get dropped. There is a lot of theory about optimal packet dropping (RED, AFD, ...) and egress packet queueing (FIFO, SFQ, CODEL) strategies.

Asynchronous systems are much more common and slowly replacing synchronous systems. It is because despite the added complexity of nodes, they don't have the overhead of stream setup and thus have a much greater ability to handle large amount of streams and adapt much faster to changes in data flows. Internet would not be possible on a synchronous system.